# Is there a spacelike curve connection two events in Minkowski space?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

Assume two events in Minkowski Space (signature $(-,+,+,+)$) $p_1$ and $p_2$. One claims that there is a spacelike curve which connects these two points in Minkowski space.

I have some trouble to prove that in a mathematical framework.

By our definition a spacelike curve is a $C^1$ curve $\xi$ fullfilling the condition $$\eta(\dot{\xi}(s),\dot{\xi}(s))>0,\quad\forall s\in I.$$

I want to argue in the following way:

Consider a $C^1$ curve $\xi(t)=(ct,x(t),y(t),z(t))$ in the domain $t\in[t_1,t_2]$ such that $\xi(t_1)=p_1$ and $\xi(t_2)=p_2$.

One checks that
$$\eta(\dot{\xi}(t),\dot{\xi}(t))=-c^2+\dot{x}^2(t)+\dot{y}^2(t)+\dot{z}^2(t)=-c^2+|v|^2$$

Since $|v|<c$ we condlude $\eta(\dot{\xi}(t),\dot{\xi}(t))<0$, which menas that $\xi$ is not spacelike.

Where is the mistake? I'm open to suggestions.

EDIT:
Firstly I considered a straight line in the time component. Now I think one should use an arbitrary function such that the condition are fullfilled. I call this function $s$.

Hence,
$$\eta(\dot{\xi}(t),\dot{\xi}(t))=-c^2\dot{s}^2(t)+\dot{x}^2(t)+\dot{y}^2(t)+\dot{z}^2(t)=-c^2\dot{s}^2(t)+|v|^2$$

The expression should larger than zero,
$$\dot{s}^2(t)<\frac{|v|^2}{c^2}\Rightarrow \dot{s}(t)<\frac{|v|}{c}$$.

Integration over $t$ yields the possible functions $s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that in the equation under "One checks that", the term $-c^2$ shouldn't be there. Instead, one should insert minus the squared value of the $t$-derivative of $c$, and the derivative of a constant is zero. This is assuming that $t$ is really a different name for $s$, an arbitrary parameter along the curve, and the letter $c$ means that the curve is located at $x^0={\rm const}$, an equal time slice.

If the letter $t$ is supposed to mean $x^0$ itself, then the expression for $\xi(t)$ is inconsistent because this curve doesn't lie in any $x^{0}={\rm const}$. Its initial component shouldn't be $c$ but rather $x^0=t$. If that's so, the curve will indeed be timelike (like a trajectory of a massive body in a spacetime), and not spacelike, if $v\lt c$ everywhere along the curve.

After this answer was written down, the question was edited and the first component $c$ was replaced by $ct$. Then indeed, this path in the spacetime is timelike, and not spacelike, as the previous paragraph says.

Comment: Thanks foru your answer. So the problem are the initial conditions? I used the representation: $p_i=(ct_i,x_i(t),y_i(t),z_i(t))$. Ommiting the $c$ should solve the problem.

Without the $t$ in the first component it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Dear @Richard, what is exactly the "problem" you are referring to? What you described, with the $ct$ as the time component, is the most widespread description of a timelike curve. That's exactly what a timelike curve is - a trajectory $\vec x(t)$ which is moving at a speed $v\lt c$ at each moment. Spacelike curves indeed correspond to propagation by $v\gt c$ in your parameterization, which is prohibited for massive objects.

Comment: The above calculation shows that every curve (connecting p_1 and p_2) is time-like. But I should argue, that there is a space-like curve connecting the two events. So is there really a possibility to connect te events with a space-like curve?

Comment: Dear Richard, you have only proved that it is a timelike curve if $v\lt c$ at every moment $t$. If $v\gt c$, the curve is spacelike. ... If two points in the Minkowski space are time-like-separated - if the straight line between them is timelike - then you won't find any spacelike trajectory between them.

Comment: You can. Just use a helix.

Comment: Dear Timur, I am afraid you ignored the condition in the sentence you disputed. The sentence is really a tautology. If you parameterize the curve so that "v" is smaller than "c" at every point, then no curve resulting from this parameterization and inequality will be spacelike. I agree of course that there are spacelike curves like helixes connecting two events.